# EKRecurreceRule: How can i set the property firstDayOfTheWeek

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, eventkit

I used the EventKit and found the property `firstDayOfTheWeek` in the `EKRecurrenceRule`, but the property is only readonly so my question does somebody know how can i set this property or how can i set any `readonly` property?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Apple's documentation on "EKRecurrenceRule"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKRecurrenceRuleClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)...

> **Note**: It is currently not possible to directly modify an
>   EKRecurrenceRule or any of its properties. This functionality is
>   achieved by creating a new EKRecurrenceRule and setting an event or
>   reminder to use the newly created rule.

In other words, **ALL** of the properties in an EKRecurrenceRule object are read-only.  Which makes sense to me: once a user sets a rule, it shouldn't be a moving target. If you want to change it, you have to create a completely new and/or separate rule.

As for the "firstDayOfTheWeek" thing, I'm not 100% certain if Apple's implementation returns the first day of the week that the recurring event happens or if it's the first practical day of the week for the calendar (whether Sunday or Monday). My guess is that it's the former. [Apple's documentation say the property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKRecurrenceRuleClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/EKRecurrenceRule/firstDayOfTheWeek) "indicates which day of the week the recurrence rule treats as the first day of the week."